# ubuntu 13.10 has exerienced a internal error

Tags: error-handling, apport

my ubuntu 13.10  is showing an error message every time when i switch on my laptop..earlier i had ubuntu 13.04 and it was also showing some error messages...so i decided to update to latest version which ended like this

what should i do to prevent seeing this..

here is the screenshot..someone please help me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually non LTS versions are not that stable. So it crashes sometimes. It's a normal thing with non LTS versions. You can remove `apport`, the package that reports errors. Use this command to remove apport:

> sudo apt-get remove apport

I had a discussion going on in a Facebook group. You may like to check it [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/Freakysoft.ubuntu/permalink/555798164500431/)
.